# Is there a theorem that tells us that $\widehat{f\circ g}=\hat f(\hat g)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Is there a theorem that tells us that $\widehat{f\circ g}=\hat f(\hat g)?$ Here, $\hat f$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171462/fourier-transform-of-function-composition)