# Fourier Transform of f(g(t)) (composite functions)?

Tags: fourier-transform

How would I compute the Fourier transform of a function $f(g(t))$ - a composite function.

For example, what if I took $h(t) = \cos(\sin(2\pi t))$, where $f(t)=\cos(t)$ and $g(t)=\sin(2\pi t)$ and attempted to find the transform of that? Is there even a solution to this problem?

By the way, I use the Fourier Transform with Kernel $e^{-i 2\pi st}$

Comment: The Fourier transform doesn't play well with function composition, unfortunately. You'll just have to brute force it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171462/fourier-transform-of-function-composition