# Fourier transform of $f(a+b t+c t^2)$

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

I would like to compute the Fourier transform of:

$$f(a+b t+c t^2)$$

for arbitrary $f$. I am aware of how to work out the Fourier transform for $f(a+bt)$. I have already looked at the [Laplace transform of $f(t^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372929/laplace-transform-of-ft2)
 post to use it as inspiration. But it stops short of what I really need.

I also had a look at [A Spectral Analysis of Function Composition and Its Implications for Sampling in Direct Volume Visualization, by Steven Bergner](http://eprints.cs.univie.ac.at/4962/1/2006_-_A_spectral_analysis_of_function_composition.pdf) but I am not sure I can use it or if there isn't a simpler way.

Thanks in advance.

Marc

Comment: why don't you complete the square, you'l get something like $(a_1t+b_1)^2+c_1$ and then do similar change of variables as the question you are referring to: $u=(a_1t+b_1)^2$