# Fourier transform of $e^{i f(x)}$ in terms of the Fourier transform of $f(x)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

For a problem I am trying to solve, I am required to calculate the Fourier transform of $e^{i  f(x)}$. However, it so happens that I do not have access to $f(x)$ but only to its Fourier transform coefficients $\mathcal{F}f(\omega)$. Are you aware of any way to define $\mathcal{F}(e^{i  f(x)})$ in terms of $\mathcal{F}f$?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Hint: does $e^{i f(x)}$ satisfy conditions to have Fourier transform?

Comment: I think so. I would think that $e^{if(x)}$ is a sort of oscillatory system since $e^{if(x)}{=}\cos(f(x)) + i \sin(f(x))$.

Comment: Hint: Fourier transform is typically defined for functions that absolutely integrable over real line. Does it hold for $e^{i f(x)}$?

Comment: From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171462/fourier-transform-of-function-composition) I would argue that it is possible. 

What I have tried so far is representing $e^{i f(x)}$ as a series $\sum_{n=0}^{\inf}\frac{((i f(x))^{n}}{n!}$, but this leads me to a series of self-convolutions on the Fourier domain, which is impractical to work with.